# How to show the function $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ has integrable derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Consider the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2\sin(1/x) & \text { if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

has integrable derivative on $(-1, 1)$.

---

I found

$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x) & \text { if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise,}
\end{cases} $$

but I have no clue how to show that it is integrable on $(-1, 1)$. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computations are correct and they show that $f'$ is bounded and it has a single discontinuity point. Therefore, it Riemann-integrable (and this would still be true if it had a countable set of discontinuity points).

Comment: Is that because the set of discontinuities is measure zero?

Comment: Indeed: a bounded function is Riemann-integrable if and only if its set of discontinuity points has measure zero.

Comment: @joseph it's much easier than that

Comment: @zhw. I agree. It's easy to prove directly from the definion (together with the fact that continuous $\implies$ Riemann-integrable) that if a bounded function only has finitely many points of discontinuity, then it is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: How do we know it is bounded?

Comment: Because $\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\in[-1,1]$ and $\lim_{x\to0}2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)=0$.

Comment: how does $\lim_{x\to 0} 2x\sin(1/x) = 0$ show it is bounded?

Comment: It shows that it is bounded near $0$, which is all that matters here. You can also say that $\left\lvert2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right\rvert\leqslant2$ for each $x\in[-1,1]$.